# npm install creates long file names that can't be pushed to

Tags: node.js, windows, git, github, npm

I have some code created in the latest version of node.js. The file names in the node_modules folder can be very longer, and are sometimes longer than GitHub Desktop will accept. When trying to push some code to GitHub, I got the error:

```
error: 

lstat("node_modules/npm/node_modules/libcipm/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/http-proxy-agent/node_modules/agent-base/node_modules/es6-promisify/node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.auto.js"): Filename too long
fatal: Unable to process path node_modules/npm/node_modules/libcipm/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/http-proxy-agent/node_modules/agent-base/node_modules/es6-promisify/node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.auto.js
```

What causes this, and what I can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the **node_modules** folder is excluded from the repository by adding it to the **.gitignore** file.

When cloning or pulling the repository you simply run the **npm install** command and all the packages are automatically downloaded to the **node_modules** folder.